# One to Many mapping in mongoose, How to receive and process?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The problem I have is a One to many mapping with mongoose(Mongodb). The one is the Order(buyer data) and the many is the Items(price,quantity,etc).

1) How I should create the Schema for the the Order and items, like should I put the items in an array in the order?

2) Would all the data be in one post function?

I herd you can use ObjectId to link the many to one but I am not sure how to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since an Order sounds like it will have a relative small number of items, the simplest thing would probably be just a list of item Ids:

```
var OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    items: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}]
});

var ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    price: Number,
    quantity: Number
});
```

Most UIs would not build an entire order in a single POST function, so it's probably best to allow creating an order and then separately adding items to it via `order.items.push(itemId)`.

Comment: So i would do something like "app.post('/uri', api.function)" for both the order and item, then in the the api(controller) have a callback in the function that creates items to push items to order?

Comment: Well yes, although creating an item sounds like it belongs in a separate inventory management app vs creating an order which is an ecommerce activity. Sorry I can't guide you in general through application design. This site is for specific programming questions.

Comment: Does this require the ItemSchema to be in the same file as the OrderSchema? I'm wondering if the ref field will be solved even if the ItemSchema is defined in another file.

Comment: No, schemas can be defined in any file, it doesn't matter. Same or different will both work. A good rule of thumb for consistently and unsurprisingness is to only have one schema per file, though.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. The docs on the mongoDB site explain how it works but they don't provide the syntax. At least I can't seem to find it.